# How to use react native navigation wix with context to share data from provider to all components?

Tags: hook, wix-react-native-navigation

I want to use react-native-navigation with context to send data from provider to all my components. I have done it as follow:

**index.js**

```
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
import {App} from './App'

App();

Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            stack:
                {
                    id: 'FoodApp',
                    children: [
                        {
                            component: {
                                id: 'myLoginId',
                                name: 'myLogin',
                                options: {
                                    topBar: {
                                        visible: false,
                                        height: 0,
                                    },
                                }
                            }
                        },

                    ],

                },
        },
    });
});
```

**App.js**

```
export const App = () => {

    Navigation.registerComponent(`myLogin`, () => (props) => (

        <GlobalProvider>
            <Login {...props} />
        </GlobalProvider>

    ), () => Login);
    Navigation.registerComponent(`myMain`, () => (props) => (

        <GlobalProvider>
            <Main {...props} />
        </GlobalProvider>

    ), () => Main);

};
```

**GlobalProvider** and **GlobalContext**

```
const GlobalContext = React.createContext();

export const GlobalProvider = ({children}) => {


    return <GlobalContext.Provider value={20}>
        {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>;
};

export default GlobalContext;
```

**Main.js**

```
const Main = () => {

    const value= useContext(GlobalContext);

    const options = (passProps) => {
        return {
            topBar: {
                height: 0,
            },

        };
    };

    return (

        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Text>Main {value}</Text>
        </View>

    );
};
```

It does not give any errors but it does not show ***value***. Please help me how to fix it. I have searched a lot but I cannot find any useful thing.

I have used:

*"react": "16.11.0",*

*"react-native": "0.62.0",*

*"react-native-navigation": "^6.3.3",*

Answer (score 1):

it's weird that the value is not showing at all as your code snippet should display `value`. I've created an example below to demonstrate integrating React Context with react-native-navigation but unfortunately as react-native-navigation is not a single root application (each registered screen is a "root") the regular Context pattern would not work as expected.

```js
// CounterContext.js
import React from 'react

const initialCounterState = {
  count: 0
}

const counterContextWrapper = (component) => ({
  ...initialCounterState,
  increment: () => {
    initialCounterState.count += 1
    component.setState({ context: contextWrapper(component) })
  },
  decrement: () => {
    initialCounterState.count -= 1
    component.setState({ context: contextWrapper(component) })
  },
})

export const CounterContext = React.createContext({})

export class CounterContextProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {
    context: counterContextWrapper(this)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CounterContext.Provider value={this.state.context}>
        {this.props.children}
      </CounterContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

```js
// index.js
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation
import { CounterContextProvider } from './CounterContext
import { Main } from './Main

Navigation.registerComponent(
  'Main', 
  () => props => (
    <CounterContextProvider>
      <Main {...props} />
    </CounterContextProvider>
  ),
  () => CounterReactContextScreen
)
```

```js
// Main.js
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { CounterContext } from './CounterContext'

export const Main = () => {
  const { count, increment, decrement } = React.useContext(CounterContext)

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{`Clicked ${count} times!`}</Text>
      <Button title="Increment" onPress={increment} />
      <Button title="Decrement" onPress={decrement} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

This should all work, however the caveat is if you register 2 screens with the same Context Provider (for example, `Main` as your root and `Pushed` as a screen that gets pushed from `Main`) if you update the value on `Pushed` screen, it would not re-render `Main` screen to show the updated value.

I'd recommend to use `MobX` if you want `Context` like API. You could checkout my boilerplate project https://github.com/jinshin1013/rnn-boilerplate.